# rake db:create giving me an error when trying to create db for open source project kandan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have finally installed all the required gems for open source project kandan and ruby on rails however whenever I try and run rake db:create I get thrown this error and i'm not sure how to fix it. If anyone could assist me that would be greatly appreciated :)

```
kandan dan$ rake db:create
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- guard/guard
/Users/dan/kandan/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dan/kandan/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- guard-spork
/Users/dan/kandan/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dan/kandan/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

For anyone interested in the --trace error:

```
rake db:create --trace
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- guard/guard
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/guard-spork-1.5.1/lib/guard/spork.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block in require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block in require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/Users/dan/kandan/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/dan/kandan/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- guard-spork
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/Users/dan/kandan/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/dan/kandan/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
```

**EDIT**

Here is what is in /Users/dan/kandan/config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

require "./lib/kandan_config.rb"

module Kandan
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Dealing with Heroku-specific eccentricities
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    config.active_record.observers = [:activity_observer, :attachment_observer, :channel_observer, :user_observer]

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    config.assets.precompile += ["admin/admin.js", "admin.css"]

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
    config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

**EDIT** Here is what is in my guardfile

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme


guard 'rspec' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end


guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end
```

**EDIT** Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Core gems
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.21'

# Database adapters
gem 'pg'

# Uncomment next line when using MySQL database
#gem 'mysql2'

# Auth gems
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.9'

# Server/transport gems
gem 'thin'
gem 'faye'

# Helper gems
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'remotipart'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'enumerize'
gem 'arel'
gem 'tzinfo'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'bourbon'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'eco'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1.0'
  gem 'sass', '3.2.13'
  gem 'gemoji', '~> 1.5.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'kandan-count'
end

group :development do
  gem 'kandan-count-dev'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  if RUBY_VERSION >= '2.0.0'
    gem 'byebug'
  else
    gem 'debugger'
  end
end

group :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  gem 'coveralls', :require => false
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'capybara'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'jasmine'
end
```

Comment: Could you please share `/Users/dan/kandan/config/application.rb:13`? Seems a dependency load issue.

Comment: Sure, check the edit for what is in that file.

Comment: What are there in your Guardfile

Comment: Do you have `gem 'guard-spork'` in your Gemfile?It looks like it is missing

Comment: I just commented out the whole line gem 'guard-spork' and it seems to be running now. DO you think this is a solution?

Comment: it was under group :development, :test do

Comment: Do you have gem 'guard' before it?

Comment: Yes I have this
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  # gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'jasmine'
end

Comment: Hmm it's crashing after login now maybe I shouldn't have commented it out

Comment: I can only say it is not problem with `rake db:create` it is problem with dependencies.I can just say try uncommenting gem 'guard-spork',Delete Guard file,Once again run `guard init rspec` ,`guard init spork`

Comment: ERROR - Could not load 'guard/spork' or '~/.guard/templates/spork' or find class Guard::Spork

Comment: Have used git hub spork like this `gem 'spork', :git => 'git://github.com/sporkrb/spork.git'`And it is better to publish your Gemfile

Comment: That command you gave me does nothing sand just sits there with an > in terminal. I added the gemfile as an edit thanks for helping so far

Comment: Dont run in the terminal add in the Gemfile

Comment: Where exactly do I put it?

Comment: Under development and test group add two gems one is one I mentioned and add one more gem `gem 'spork-rails'` that has to be before `gem 'guard-spork'`,Then run `bundle install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Gemfile I can say that you are missing spork in your Gemfile 
Edit your Gemfile like this

```
 group :development, :test do
      gem 'sqlite3'
      gem 'spork', :git => 'git://github.com/sporkrb/spork.git'
      gem 'spork-rails' 
      gem 'guard'
      gem 'guard-rspec'
      gem 'guard-spork'
      gem 'database_cleaner'
      gem 'jasmine'
    end
```

Then run `bundle install`
Initialize it by running in terminal

```
spork rspec --bootstrap
```

Re generate your Guardfile by running

```
guard init rspec
gurad init spork
```

Comment: Thanks for this informative response. The server now crashes as soon as it starts with this error. http://pastebin.com/DJAxi7V4

Comment: That issue is now solved.Try running rake db:migrate,Please accept my answer if it was helpful,And The other problem as a new question

Comment: Thanks, I accepted you as best answer and added a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882426/ruby-on-rails-server-crashing-when-adding-a-new-account-for-open-source-project